# Splitting lines in text file using tab delimiter - Java

Tags: java, file, split, delimiter

I have a text file containing words and their corresponding meanings and each word-meaning pair is separated by two tab spaces

```
Cat     Animal with four legs
Bus     Mean of transport
NUST        University in asia
Corolla     Car manufacturing company
Chemistry       Science subject
Cricket     Game played with bat and ball
Camouflage      Hide or disguise the presence of any object
```

I want to read each line and split them by delimiter `\\t\\t` so that i can separate words from their meanings. Below is the function i wrote to do this

```
public static void readFile() {
     try{
         String line;
         String[] lineparts;
         Scanner pw = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dictfile.txt")));

         while(pw.hasNext()) {
             line = pw.nextLine();
             lineparts = line.split("\\t\\t");
             System.out.println(lineparts[0]);
         }

     }catch(IOException ex){

         System.out.println(ex);
     }
}
```

but the output is not as i expect. Array named `lineparts` which receives the returned strings from `split()` method should contain a word at its zero index and that word's meaning at its first index but the actual output is different.

**Actual output**

```
Cat     Animal with four legs
Bus     Mean of transport
NUST        University in asia
Corolla     Car manufacturing company
Chemistry       Science subject
Cricket     Game played with bat and ball
Camouflage      Hide or disguise the presence of any object
```

**Expected output**

```
Cat  
Bus     
NUST        
Corolla     
Chemistry       
Cricket     
Camouflage
```

What am i doing wrong here and how can i achieve the expected output ?

Comment: Are you sure that you have 2 tabs in the file? In your description I don't see any tabs, only spaces.

Comment: yes i wrote in to file manually and added two tab spaces between each word and its meaning

Comment: If the columns are really separated by 2 tabs, the posted code should work. Check the file's content using `hexdump -C` command. You will probably see that it's NOT 2 tabs.

Answer (score 2):

Some of your text is delimited with double tabs but some is also separated with single tabs. The Regular Expression in your **split()** method should look like this:

```
lineparts = line.split("\t+");
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use the escape sequence `\\t\\t`, instead you just want the tab `\t\t`. If you use the escape sequence you're saying that you want to split the lines with the characters \t as the delimiter.

Comment: As Parco said don’t escape \. We tend to forget that split is regex based.